# Does there exist a basis of $\mathbb R^3$ consisting of eigenvectors of T?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, adjoint-operators, self-adjoint-operators

**True or false (and give a proof)**: There exists
$T ∈ L(\mathbb R^3)$ such that $T$ is not self-adjoint (with respect to the usual inner product) and such that there exists a basis of $\mathbb R^3$
consisting of eigenvectors of T.

**Attempt:** Although, I possess a counter-example. But, I am unable to find a flaw in this argument:

If there exists a basis of $\mathbb R^3$ consisting of eigenvectors of T, then, the matrix of $T$ denoted by $M(T)$ is a diagonal matrix. Since, $M(T^*), ~(T^* \text{is the adjoint operator)}$ is the conjugate transpose of $M(T)$, thus $M(T^*)=M(T)$ is a diagonal matrix, hence, $T$ is self-adjoint.

( The above argument seeking equality between $M(T)~ \text {and}~M(T^*)$ is valid because there exists an isomorphism between $T$ and $M(T)$.

What could be the error in this argument?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: $T$ is a diagonal matrix **with respect to some basis**.  But that basis may not be an orthogonal basis, so the matrix of $T^*$ may not be the transpose of the matrix of $T$.

Comment: @GEdgar A basis with respect to which a diagonal matrix exists, must be orthogonal also right? Consider $\{(1,0,0).(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\}$

Comment: Fix your favourite invertible matrix $V$ such that its rows are not mutually orthogonal and your favourite diagonal matrix $D$ with distinct diagonal entries. Then, $T=V^{-1} DV$ is diagonalisable, but its basis of eigenvectors is not an orthogonal basis.

Comment: @GEdgar got it thanks!

Comment: Oh well, it seems that you'd solved the problem as I was typing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you diagonalise a matrix, you change the basis:

$$D=PMP^{-1}$$

$D$ is diagonal, hence $D^T=D$ indeed, but from this you cannot conclude that $M^D=M$, **unless** $P$ is orthogonal (where $P^{-1}=P^T$).

An operator being self adjoint (over a Euclidean vector space) doesn't mean that its matrix is symmetric with respect to any basis, only with respect to an orthogonal basis.

Another way to see it is that if you make a non-orthogonal change of basis, you twist the inner product upon which the notion of adjoint operator relies.